# Date.getTime() in Java returning different time in different server

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat, milliseconds, java.util.date

I need to calculate a value that is based on dates. So I'm parsing the date first using date format class and then i'm using `getTime()` to get milliseconds. With those milliseconds i'll calculate some value. But `getTime()` is returning different values in different servers. We develop here in India, where i'm getting correct value but in US server i'm getting different value.

Scenario:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        String now = "11/03/2018";

        Date UsualDateformat = sdf.parse(now);

        System.out.println(UsualDateformat.getTime());
    }
}
```

Above is a sample code, but my actual code is a rule in a drl file (drools).
This program returns
"1541183400000" which i convert to date is "Sat 3 November 2018 00:00:00".,
but in US server im getting "1541217600000" equal to date "Sat 3 November 2018 09:30:00".
So when i use this value i'm getting marginal decimal point formatting issue.
How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the timezone to GMT and it will be correct.

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are still using the long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class? Today we have so much better in [`java.time` or JSR-310, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the time zone on SimpleDateFormat to be consistent across servers in different regions.  For example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        ....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You get these different values, because the time difference between your server in the US and the one in India is 9h 30.

This has nothing to do with floating points, but with time zones.

One way to solve this problem is to work always within the same time zone (e.g. India)

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet might work for you,

```
public static String getGmtTime(String timezone) {
    return ZonedDateTime
            .now()
            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(timezone))
            .toLocalDateTime()
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

pass `timezone` as `America/Los_Angeles` to get time with proper timezone,
Timezones can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: Please explain how it may solve the OP’s question? I think the OP asked for milliseconds?

Comment: Simpler: `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(timezone)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))` (gives the same result).

Answer (score 1):

### `java.time`

I recommend you use `java.time`, also known as JSR-310, for this. The classes you use, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, are long outdated, and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular has a reputation for producing surprising results, which one may say also happened in your case. The modern API is generally so much nicer to work with.

As I think you have suspected already, your issue comes from the fact that your servers are running different time zones, and the conversion of a date to millis since the epoch is a time zone dependent operation since the epoch is always the same point in time (Jan 1 1970 at midnight *in UTC*). As [mweiss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47322578/5772882) I am using UTC for the conversion to make sure it gives the same result no matter the time zone of the server:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String now = "11/03/2018";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(now, dtf);
    long millisInUtc = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(millisInUtc);
```

As my code stands, it prints

```
1541203200000
```

This is between the values you got in India and US because UTC is between those two time zones. If you consider it more correct to use for example Asia/Kolkata time, simply substitute `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")` instead of `ZoneOffset.UTC` in the code, and you should get the same output as you already got when you ran your code on your server in India (please remember to rename the variable too).

My code is a bit longer than yours. I consider this an advantage in this case. Yes, indeed. The code using `java.time` is making explicit that we are using the time at the start of the day (0:00 midnight) and that we are using a time zone or offset for the conversion. This forces you as the coder to think about these issues, and you will be very unlikely to write code that produces results that differ unexpectedly across time zones, that is, your issue would never arise. At the same time it makes explicit to the reader that the operation depends on time zone, and that you have made a conscious choice of which zone to use. These advantageous are *well* worth a few more code lines.